# How to convert hex string into Japanese and write it to the file in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to convert a hex string into Japanese(codec: SHIFT-JIS) and write the Japanese output to a file using Python 2.7. However, all I have got is the original hex string in the file. Can someone tell me where I did wrong? Here is the code I use:

```
fd = open(path,'w')
temp_str ='\x8d\xc5\x82\xe0\x8d\x82\x8b\x4d\x82\xc8\x89\xa4\x82\xc5\x82\xa0\x82\xc1\x82\xbd\x82\xbc\x81\x76\x80\x01\xff\xff'
fd.write(temp_str.encode('shift-jis'))
fd.close()
```

All I have got in the file is "\x8d\xc5\x82\xe0\x8d\x82\x8b\x4d\x82\xc8\x89\xa4\x82\xc5\x82\xa0\x82\xc1\x82\xbd\x82\xbc\x81\x76\x80\x01\xff\xff".

Answer (score 1):

The string seems to be encoded in UTF-16BE:

```
>>> print temp_str.decode('utf_16_be')
跅苠趂譍苈覤苅芠苁芽芼腶老
```

But it also seems malformed, ie, it was cut halfway. You should first convert the string to Unicode by decoding the bytes:

```
uni_str = temp_str.decode('utf_16_be')
```

And then saving the Unicode string to a file with an encoding that you want:

```
fd = open(path,'w')
fd.write(uni_str.encode('shift-jis'))
fd.close()
```

However, the codec 'shift-jis' doesn't seem to like your string:

```
>>> print uni_str.encode('shift_jis')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't encode character u'\u8dc5' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

This is not Japanese, but Chinese:

```
>>> print uni_str.encode('gb18030')
ڗ���f�G���B�i�[��ѿ�d�a�τ1�9
```

'gb18030' is a Chinese codec, [according to Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html).

Yes, its jiggebirsh because I don't have a terminal with that codec, but it is the only codec from Python that encodes the string without errors besides UTF8/16/32.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should open file in "wb" instead "w" mode?